# Column name starts with numeric handling in Amazon Athena

Tags: sql, json, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I loaded json file in s3 location ,in which a key starts with numeric (3party_count).I created table in aws Athena on top of this location by using crawler n aws glue.so column names has be created named 3party_count
But I couldn't do select query using this column ?
Error -invalid request exception

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: SQL typically doesn't like column names starting with a digit. Try putting it in quotes, eg `"3party_count"`. You could also take the DDL that the crawler created and modify it to create a table with a different column heading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..but first option gave me the column name can't be resolved error . I queried like Select "party.type.3party_count" from table name.since 3party_count S second level nested key in my json file

Comment: Second option, I created a new table with newcol name but query can able to retrieve Vakue since there S no such key in my json file

Comment: Oops! Didn't notice you were using JSON.

Comment: Can you try using `\`` instead of `"` for quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "123view" AS
SELECT column_name1, column_name2
FROM "234table"
```

[Names for Tables, Databases, and Columns AWS Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html)